# react hooks help refactor from class based component

Tags: javascript, react-hooks

I had this class based component that I am trying to refactor to use hooks and am running into some trouble I can't figure out.  I have a surveyquestion component that will display a dropbox, checkbox, etc depending on the type of question that was created.  However, I can't seem to figure out where I can re-initialize the underlying values when there is a new question.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  I am only showing the checkbox component functions.

```
const CheckboxButton = ({ onClick, checked, label }) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={checkboxStyles.wrapper}
      activeOpacity={1}
      onPress={() => {
        if (typeof onClick === 'function') {
          onClick(!checked);
        }
      }}
    >
      <View
        style={[
          checkboxStyles.checkbox,
          checked ? checkboxStyles.checkboxChecked : null
        ]}
      >
        {checked ? <View style={checkboxStyles.checkboxCheckedDot} /> : null}
      </View>
      <Text style={checkboxStyles.label}>{label}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

const QuestionCheckboxes = ({ question, onChange }) => {
  const [checkedIndex, setCheckedIndex] = useState([]);

  const _onChange = checked => {
    const options = question.options;
    let values = [];

    for (let i in checked) {
      if (checked[i]) {
        values.push(options[i]);
      }
    }

    if (typeof onChange === 'function') {
      onChange(values.length ? values : null);
    }
  };

  let items = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < question.options.length; ++i) {
    const option = question.options[i];
    items.push(
      <CheckboxButton
        key={i}
        label={option}
        checked={checkedIndex[i]}
        onClick={value => {
          let newCheckedIndex = [...checkedIndex];
          newCheckedIndex[i] = value;
          setCheckedIndex(newCheckedIndex);
          //need to use newCheckedIndex for onChange b/c checked index has been set
          _onChange(newCheckedIndex);
        }}
      />
    );
  }

  return <View>{items}</View>;
};

const QuestionView = ({ index, question, onChange }) => {
  const questionComponents = {
    dropdown: QuestionDropdown,
    radios: QuestionRadios,
    checkboxes: QuestionCheckboxes,
    stars: QuestionStars
  };

  if (typeof questionComponents[question.type] !== 'function') {
    return null;
  }

  const QuestionComponent = questionComponents[question.type];

  return (
    <View>
      <Text style={styles.questionTitle}>
        {index}. {question.title}
      </Text>
      <View style={styles.questionComponent}>
        <QuestionComponent question={question} onChange={onChange} />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const SurveyQuestion = ({ navigation }) => {

  const [survey, setSurvey] = useState(navigation.getParam('item'));
  const questionsCount = survey.entity.data.length;
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(1);
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(index / questionsCount);
  const [answers, setAnswers] = useState([]);

  _nextQuestion = async () => {
    setProgress(index / questionsCount);
    if (typeof answers[current] === 'undefined' || answers[current] === null) {
      // GeneralActions.notify('Please answer this question.');
      console.log('did not answer question');
      return;
    }

    if (current === survey.entity.data.length - 1) {
      console.log('getting ready to send to server');
      try {
        const response = await axios.post('/request', {
          id: survey.id,
          key: null,
          data: answers
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('error posting survey: ', err);
      }
      return null;
    }
    setCurrent(current + 1);
    setIndex(index + 1);
  };

  return (
    <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.questions}>
          <View style={styles.progressbar}>
            <ProgressBar
              progress={progress}
              width={null}
              height={20}
              borderRadius={10}
              borderWidth={0}
              unfilledColor='#f5f5f5'
            />
          </View>
          <Text style={styles.questionsInfo}>
            {index} / {questionsCount}
          </Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.questionWrapper}>
          <QuestionView
            index={index}
            question={survey.entity.data[current]}
            onChange={value => {
              let newAnswers = answers.slice();
              newAnswers[current] = value;
              setAnswers(newAnswers);
            }}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.action}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.buttonPrimary}
            activeOpacity={0.7}
            onPress={_nextQuestion}
          >
            <Text style={styles.button}>
              {progress === 1 ? 'FINISH' : 'NEXT'}
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};
```

Currently when I move from question to question, the old answers will carry over.  I can't figure out where I can re-initialize the checkedIndex back to [] for example.

const [checkedIndex, setCheckedIndex] = useState([]);

I tried putting setCheckedIndex([]) in a few areas and was getting too many re-renders.

Comment: It's likely because it's reusing the same `QuestionComponent ` component between each render. I wasn't able to test it, but I would try adding a unique `key` to provide a "hint" to React that it should create a new component whenever the key changes:

`<QuestionComponent key={question.uniqueIdOrSomething} question={question} onChange={onChange} />`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  How do I tell react to create a new component based on the key?

Comment: Adding a key attribute worked, it will cause the component to re-mount.  Thanks Skovy!

Comment: Awesome, glad that worked! I'll create an answer to formalize it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely because it's reusing the same `QuestionComponent` component between each render. I wasn't able to test it, but I would try adding a unique key to provide a "hint" to React that it should create a new component whenever the key changes.

```
<QuestionComponent
  key={question.uniqueIdOrSomething}
  question={question}
  onChange={onChange}
/>;
```

Where `uniqueIdOrSomething` could be the question `id` or question `text` (anything that can uniquely identify the question).

Generally, the `key` is used in a list so React can reuse the components if the order would change (performance optimization). However, it can also be used to tell React this component is *different* and it shouldn't reuse the existing component and re-instantiate it. For you, this will wipe the existing state and give you the fresh defaults. I think this is the right use case for using `key`, but be careful overusing this approach (adding a `key` prop) because it could be masking other problems.

More details on the `key` attribute: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html